# Purposefully failing a JUnit test upon method completion

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, junit

### Background

I am working with a Selenium/Junit test environment and I want to implement a class to perform "soft asserts": meaning that I want it to record whether or not the assert passed, but not actually fail the test case until I explicitly tell it to validate the Asserts. This way I can check multiple fields on a page an record all of the ones which do not match.

---

### Current Code

My "verify" methods appear as such (similar ones exist for `assertTrue`/`assertFalse`):

```
public static void verifyEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
    try {
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        verificationFailuresList.add(e);
    }
}
```

Once all the fields have been verified, I call the following method:

```
public static void checkAllPassed() {
    if (!verificationFailuresList.isEmpty()) {
        for (Throwable failureThrowable : verificationFailuresList) {
            log.error("Verification failure:" + failureThrowable.getMessage(), failureThrowable);
            // assertTrue(false);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Question

At the moment, I am currently just using `assertTrue(false)` as a way to quickly fail the test case; however, this clutters the log with a nonsense failure and pushes the real problem further up. Is there a cleaner way to purposefully fail a JUnit testcase? If not, is there a better solution to implement soft asserts? I know of an [article](http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/guide/using-soft-assertions-in-testng/) which has a very well done implementation, but to my knowledge JUnit has no equivalent to the IInvokedMethodListener class

Comment: http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html#fail%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to fail a JUnit test on purpose you should use [org.junit.Assert.fail()](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#fail())

Other option is to switch to TestNG framework which already has a `SoftAssert` class in it's [latest version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.8.21).

Answer (score 1):

You can use JUnit's [ErrorCollector](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ErrorCollector.html) rule.